# Trying to pass parameter by ref using list doesn't work?

Tags: python

The function `update` in the following code tries to update a tree in place. Since Python doesn't support pass by ref so the function `update` has a parameter of `list` (https://realpython.com/python-pass-by-reference/).

However, `n` was not updated after called `update([n])`?

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def update(ns):
    ns[0] = ns[0].left

n = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2), TreeNode(3))
update([n])
# n is not updated, n should be replaced by the left child of the n (2).
```

Comment: "Since Python doesn't support pass by ref" - any reference? Have you tried passing `n` directly?

Comment: Python always passes by object reference, why do you think it doesn't? You don't need to use a list at all.

Comment: @JanStránský "officially", Python passes "references by value" (or "by assignment"), but only for mutable objects. This has been heavily discussed, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: @DeepSpace I was more interested in the OP's source. Passing `n` directly to `update` and modifying it inside the function would change it in-place, as OP wants. Because it is passed "by ref"

Comment: @JanStránský OP's situation is tricky because they want to change the object itself, not an attribute on it. Doing `def update(local_n): local_n = local_n.left`  and calling `update(n)` will not modify the object that was passed to `update`, it will just create a new local variable `local_n` and dispose it, leaving the original unchanged

Comment: working with trees is tricky by default :-) If the requirement is to modify in place, then OP should modify the tree in place. @ca9163d9, could you please provide expected output after `update`?

Comment: @JanStránský a TreeNode with val of 2 and no child. I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ns[0]` and `ns[0] = xxx` are synthatic sugar in python:

`ns[0]` means [item 0 of s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common) and internaly calls [`ns.__getitem__(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

`ns[0] = xxx` means [item 0 of ns is replaced by xxx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) and internaly calls [`ns.__setitem__(0, xxx)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__).

It is different than writing `myvar = xxx`.

so in your `update` function, you are only mutating the list `ns` which is only visible inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> n = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2), TreeNode(3))
> update([n])
> # n is not updated
> ```

No, `n` is not updated.

What's updated is `[n]`, but you don't see it because you didn't keep a reference to it before passing it to `update()`.

If you use

```
ns = [n]
update(ns)
```

you should see that `ns` has been changed.

Comment: Right. I'd emphasis that after the update, `ns` must be inspected, not `n`. Doing `ns = [n] ; 
print(n) ; 
update(ns) ; 
print(n)` will not show an update, but `ns = [n] ;
print(ns[0]) ;
update(ns) ;
print(ns[0])` will.

Comment: No, I tried `ns = [n]` and then `update(ns)`, `n` was still not updated.

Comment: @ca9163d9 See my comment above. I explained what you should do

Comment: @DeepSpace, yes, `ns[0]` will got the updated value.

Answer (score 1):

To update the tree in place, one option is to overwrite the attributes

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def update(n): # passed by reference!
    m = n.left # m ... node to be copied
    n.val,n.left,n.right = m.val,m.left,m.right # overwriting n attributes by m attributes

n = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2), TreeNode(3))

print(n)
print(n.val,n.left,n.right) # original node
update(n)
print(n)
print(n.val,n.left,n.right) # changed node (but still the same instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, variables are labels that map to a memory reference. `a=b` just remaps the reference for a to the reference for b. So what you're trying to do with lists shenanigans is literally what Python does automatically with the assignment operator:

```
def update(ns):
    return ns.left

n = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2), TreeNode(3))
n = update(n)
```